# Extending Added Types in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to create an extensible set of types that can be dynamically added to PowerShell scripts.

I have the following three files in the same directory.  When I run the .ps1 file, the first  type (T.ObjectBase) is added without error.  The second however, generates the error: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ObjectBase' does not exist in the namespace 'T' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

Can I make the first class visible to the second without compiling it into a dll?

```
// T.cs
namespace T;  
public class ObjectBase {  
    private static int _id = 0;  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public ObjectBase() => this.Id = ++_id;  
}
```

```
// T_Derived.cs 
using T;
namespace T.Derived;
public class TD : T.ObjectBase {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TD(string name) : base() => this.Name = name;
}
```

```
# T.ps1
Add-Type .\T.cs
Add-Type .\T_Derived.cs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each invocation of `Add-Type` will write all the requested type definitions to disk and then do a single isolated pass of the resulting compilation unit through a C# compiler.

The compiler doesn't have access to the application domain hosting PowerShell, and so won't be able to see types emitted by previous invocations of `Add-Type`.

The solution is to pass *all* source files to `Add-Type` at once:

```
Add-Type -Path .\T.cs,.\T_Derived.cs
```

Comment: You're right!  Unfortunately, that forces me to load all potential types at once.  I suppose I can live with that.